# Compiling proto3 files in VS2015 C# project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, protobuf-net

What is the easiest way to build C# classes from .proto files in VS2015 project?

I added **Grpc** packages to my project and have protoc.exe somewhere deep in nuget package folder. I could invoke protoc in pre-build event or add custom tool for .proto file but it seems very clumsy as path to protoc is really long and it may change with nuget package version.